# Create virtual lines in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Due to our requirement, the default "Add Feature" will not work for us.
So we decided to create a new GUI which validates and does some calculation before changing a layer. This GUI holds the information in a list and based on some conditions decides which layer/layers to edit.

My add-feature tool needs to be similar to the default one, with default add-feature as soon as you click it starts drawing an arbitrary line on the canvas.
Similar to the following picture.

[image: QGIS Map Canvas]

How can I represent the information on the QGIS map canvas without adding any new layer?

In short, I want to draw lines/polygons on map canvas. These lines and polygons are totally virtual and after execution of GUI will be removed. Is there a function/class which does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the class QgsRubberBands. 
Rubber Bands draw temporary objects on the map canvas without adding new layers.

[Instructions from pyqgis cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#rubber-bands-and-vertex-markers)